# IdentityServer handling timeouts and subsequent redirects

Tags: identityserver3

I've implemented IdentityServer3 in my application and it has been working really good. However recently I came across some behaviour I can't quite figure out so I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm either doing wrong or how I should be doing the following:

I have a ASP.NET MVC application that uses IdentityServer for authentication. The user authenticates and opens a specific page within the application. He moves away from his PC, comes back a little later and clicks another link within the application (e.g. controller/action/38). The application then redirects the user to:

`http://localhost/MyIdentityServer/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=myapp&redirect_uri=http://localhost/MyApp/controller/action/38&response_mode=form_post&response_type=id_token&scope=openid+profile+roles etc.`

Since only the root url of the app (http://localhost/MyApp) is registered as a RedirectUrl in IdentityServer it shows the following message:

*The client application is not known or is not authorized.*

Rightfully so, since the controller + action aren't valid RedirectUrls. However, I cannot image that I'd have to add all the controllers and actions to the RedirectUrl property, especially since they take data-related parameters. Surely I must be doing something wrong but what?

Comment: How are you supplying the redirect_uri? Could you show your OWIN Startup file, if you're using the OIDC middleware?

Comment: The clients are currently being supplied using a static class where they're defined and added in Startup.cs as follows:

`application.Map("/identity", configuration =>
            {
                var factory = InMemoryFactory.Create(
                    clients: Clients.Get(),
                    scopes: Scopes.Get()
                );
});`

Each of the clients in Clients.Get() simply sets the RedirectUrl property to its root Url.

Comment: Yeah, that's okay - but how about MyApp..?

Comment: That's a bit too big to put in here, so I uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/d5yRmC18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the redirecturi provided to idsrv on each request to idsrv:

remove this line:

```
   notification.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = something
```